# How do you set an "If" option on an entry that includes "contains"

Tags: templating

I am trying to set an `if` statment that will show a `li` if there is only one entry displaying. The issue I am having is that this entry is put into two different places via checking if it contains a checkbox.
I can only seem to managed to get it to display all the time or not at all

The code I have at the moment is this
    `{% if entry.ENTRYNAME.contains('CHECKBOX OPTION') == 0 %} <li>CONTENT</li> {% endif %}`

But that does not seem to work.
I am using the Check box contains option else where and it works fine. It's  just the value check that I cannot seem to get to work. I've also tried adding both `.length` and `|length` but neither of those seem to work.

Comment: I'm confused on a few things... what does "one entry displaying" mean? What is `ENTRYNAME` in your example?  Is that an Entries field (http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields)?

Comment: @BradBell I made a mistake. `ENTRYNAME` Is actually `FIELDNAME` which is a checkbox field. I figured out how to solve the issue and have posted the answer bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OKay so the solution I found is this. It was much more complicated than I wanted it to be but it works.

```
{% set VARIABLE = 0 %}
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('ENTRY') %}
    {% if entry.FIELDNAME.contains('CHECKBOX OPTION') %}
        {% set VARIABLE = VARIABLE + 1 %}
        <li>CONTENT</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if VARIABLE <= 1 %}
    <li>CONTENT</li>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, so I don't know if these suggestions will help at all.

If you want to check if a checkbox field only has one option checked then you can simply use

```
{% if entry.FIELDNAME|length == 1 %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

If you're trying to show it in one location if a certain checkbox is checked, and a different location if a different checkbox is checked, then try...

```
{# location one (maybe header) #}
{% if entry.FIELDNAME.contains("Use Location 1") %}
    <li>CONTENT</li>
{% endif %}

{# elsewhere, location two (maybe footer) #}
{% if entry.FIELDNAME.contains("Use Location 2") %}
    <li>CONTENT</li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I have pretty much that exact set up for sorting my `<li>` and it does work but that was not the issue I was struggling with this time. What I needed to do now was check how many entries had option 1 ticked in the checkbox and if that number was below 1 display another `<li>`. I did figure this out above though. Thanks for the suggstion though